# How do I graph the unit circle of the following inner product space, (all (x,y) a distance of one from the origin)?

Tags: linear-algebra

The question at first was to verify that $\langle(x,y),(m,n)\rangle=2xm+yn$ is an inner product space.

I have done this part and verified that it is indeed an inner product space, but how do I graph the inner product space on the unit circle (all $(x,y)$ a distance of one from the origin), which is the final part of the question?

Comment: The unit circle is $S=\lbrace (x,y):\langle (x,y),(x,y)\rangle=1\rbrace$. Thus, $$S= \lbrace (x,y): 2x^2+y^2=1\rbrace$$ This means that the unit circle is nothing but the graph of $y=\pm\sqrt{1-2x^2}$ which Im afraid it is an ellipse.

Answer (score 2):

You have $$\langle(x,y),(x,y)\rangle=2x^2+y^2$$ and so the "unit circle" is the ellipse defined by $$2x^2+y^2=1.$$

Comment: Thank you very much !!!